# Values from another table not working in Group by(SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I have two tables in my Database.

First Table

```
ID | Count of ID's
------------------
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | 4
4  | 1
5  | 3
```

Second Table

```
ID | Count of ID's
------------------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3
4  | 5
5  | 7
```

Now, I want to divide the Count of ID's from First Table to Second Table and then group by the ID of the first table.

Basically the expected output is

```
ID | Entropy
------------------
1  | 2
2  | 1.5
3  | 1.3
4  | 0.2
5  | 0.42
```

My Query:

```
 Select t1.ID, Sum(t1.[Count of ID's]/t2.[Count of ID's])
 from FirstTable t1, SecondTable t2 
 group by t1.ID;
```

I don't think I am using the group by effectively. Can somebody help me with this please?

The problem I am encountering is the sum is aggregating all the values (2+1.5+1.3+0.2+ 0.42= 5.42) and displaying it with every ID.

Current Output( Wrong one)

```
ID | Entropy
------------------
1  | 5.42
2  | 5.42
3  | 5.42
4  | 5.42
5  | 5.42
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query produces cartisian product of the two tables, because of `from FirstTable t1, SecondTable t2`. `JOIN` them instead:

```
Select t1.ID, Sum(1.0 * t1.[Count of ID's]/t2.[Count of ID's]) AS Entropy
from FirstTable t1
INNER JOIN  SecondTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the columns which defines their relationship on the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.[Count of IDs] * 1.0 / b.[Count of IDs] * 1.0 Entropy
FROM    FirstTable a
        INNER JOIN secondTable b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77cab/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)